# the numerical values given in data-ng-init

Tags: angularjs

```
<div data-ng-app="" data-ng-init="quantity=1;price=20">  
<h2>Cost Calculator</h2>  
Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="quantity">  
Price: <input type="number" ng-model="price">  
<p><b>Total in rupees:</b> {{quantity * price}}</p>  
</div>
```

Hi guys, i am currently studying AngularJs Data Binding, and i have a question about the code above. Can anyone explain what these two numerical values,'1' and '20', in data-ng-init stand for? Every time i click on the input for quantity and price, the numbers for both input increase and decrease by a value 1, instead of 1 and 20 respectively.
Also, what is the difference between data-ng-app and data-ng-init?

Comment: *" what is the difference between data-ng-app and data-ng-init"* ... both are explained in the documentation

Comment: which documentation are u referring to?

Comment: The angular js documentation. When in doubt, read the manual

Answer (score 0):

ng-init runs when the view is loaded so in this quantify and price are default getting set by ng-init to 1 and 20 , ng-app is a directive to denote that from here onwards anything inside this div is a angular app and ng-init is used to execute expression or value on the load of the view.And by default the input values will increase and decrease by 1 only as it is default functionality of input type=number it is nothing to do with whatever default we are setting in ng-init so your value increases and decreases by 1